# C# read each line from text file and update label with each line

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, io, streamreader

I have a C# program that should be iterating through a log file, line by line, and then updating a label based on what it reads, however, I get an unhandled exception.

The file that it is reading from is coming from another external c++ program that is writing to the log (I want this C# wrapper program to be able to redirect output from the text to this window (and the only way I could think of was to read from the log from c# as the c++ program wrote to the log.

Here is the code:

```
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\scan.cmd";
p.Start();
//p.WaitForExit();
// Read the file and display it line by line.
string logFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\log.txt";
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(logFile);
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && p.HasExited == false)
{
   itemBeiingScanned_Label.Content = line;
}

file.Close();
```

And here is the exception (occurs twice)-

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SpywareKing.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

And here is the debug code:

```
64e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x20c0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x13b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x383c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2838 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'SpywareKing.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpywareKing.vshost.exe): Loaded     'C:\Users\Jaycen\Documents\Dev\SpywareKing\SpywareKing\bin\x64\Release\SpywareKing.exe'.     Symbols loaded.
'SpywareKing.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpywareKing.vshost.exe): Loaded     'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Acc    essibility.dll'. Symbols loaded.
SpywareKing.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpywareKing.vshost.exe): Loaded     C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SpywareKing.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SpywareKing.vshost.exe): Loaded     'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type     'SpywareKing.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'SpywareKing.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

The program '[14348] SpywareKing.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception happens when you read from the log, and not just when creating the Window?  Comment out the reader code and see?

Comment: The exception appears to be related to XAML / WPF, which is the presentation (display) framework for your app.  Is this code in the constructor of your main window?  Perhaps try commenting out this code and making sure the program runs, or move the code into a console app to isolate.

Comment: Also - instead of reading a file (which can have contention issues) - you could instead have your CMD simply echo its results out to standard output and read that using your Process object's .StandardOutput property (`p.StandardOutput`) which is a StreamReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It seemed the problem was that there were too many background processes of the same instance running, that I accidentally forgot to close. However, my problem now, is that it does not update the label in real time, in only updates once. 

Is there anyway to update this real time?

Comment: But you are only reading the file once.  One option might to use a FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the C++ application has locked the file for exclusive access. Do you have access to the source code so you can check and change that if necessary? If so make sure it opens the file with shared access (not sure what that looks like in C++). If you do then manage to get the file open in your WPF application, you need to make sure you open it with shared access so you don't block access to it by the C++ application. Take a look at FileStream (last parameter `FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)`).

I would also recommend moving your code out of the Window constructor (where I'm assuming it is based on the exception) and wrap it in exception handling so that you can get a more meaningful exception which I'm guessing is `System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file 'log.txt' because it is being used by another process`.

Some other considerations are, what happens when your stream reader catches up to the writing? Your loop will end and you'll end up with only the last line of the log file (at that time) in your label. You may need a more elaborate solution that either monitors the file for changes or the length of the file and your current index.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code working by removing the "\\" from "\\log.txt" + "&& p.HasExited == false" as I don't have the process to test.

Nearly forgot remove the "\\" from the "p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\scan.cmd";"

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Process p = new Process();
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\scan.cmd";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        string logFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt";
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(logFile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            itemBeiingScanned_Label.Content = line;
        }

        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Regards,
Eugene